# parse error for updating devicetoken in installation table

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to update `deviceToken` of `parse` `Installation`  table. i am using via `rest` api for android. but whenever i update my `devicetoken`  via following code

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
LinkedList<String> channels = new LinkedList<String>();     
channels.add("Giants");    
installation.put("channels",channels);     
installation.put("GCMSenderId","56698194487");     
installation.put("deviceToken","abcd");    
installation.saveInBackground();
```

I got following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify
>   `deviceToken` property of an _Installation object.

I tried to delete `session` and `installation` table but nothing works could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to update **deviceToken**, you can use "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" broadcast intent to your app and have parse android (as of 1.15.7 com.parse.GcmRegistrar.java) pick it and update the deviceToken.

This is useful esp when you FCM and parse server (as of 2.3.8) still looking for deviceToken id to send FCM notification.

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION");
            i.putExtra("registration_id", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
            sendBroadcast(i);
```

Make sure you have this in android manifest, apart from com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT and INSTANCE_ID_EVENT intent filters

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Works!
But we still have to change the `pushType` field.
How can we do it?

Comment: When do you recommend sending the broadcast you mentioned in your answer? Would you do it in the `onTokenRefresh` callback of the FirebaseInstanceIdService?

Answer (score 0):

`deviceToken` field is `read only` in `Installation` so you can't modify or update them.

`Parse.com` `android` [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-installations)

> deviceToken: The token used by GCM to keep track of registration ID.
>   On iOS devices, this is the Apple generated token (readonly).

Comment: thank you kishore for your answer . then how can i send push notification using rest api without any devicetoken at parse database . Actually i want to send push notification with help of rest api . i already have function at cloud code . i update the gcmsenderid and server key at parse but there is no place to send registration id ( devicd token) . any dwmo or example to send puah notification?

Comment: the `deviceToken` will be generated for you when you create a Parse.Installation object and save it.

Comment: yes its generated when someone use com.parse.gcmbroadcastreciever . it is actually default  pushnotification provided by parse but there is way to use customize gcm push notification . but i was able to send push notification via default but dont know how can i send push notification via own gcm . its possible to update device token via coding in ios but dont know how can i do in android? anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing same problem. Please find solution here.

link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B04Quls_ltDDNnVrRE55Yk9sb2M?usp=sharing

1. Extract attached file and add it as a module in your project.
2. Mention this module file in settings.gradle.
3. Add this statements in your app moduel in build.gradle, like

```
//compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'   //Comment it if available
compile project(':Parse-release')   //Use this one.
```

4. Clean build and Build once.

Note: I hope this custom library will help you to update deviceToken, since in this library deviceToken is editable rest everything is same.